# Quiero evaluar un dataframe, comparando valores de varias columnas pero leyendo por fila

Tags: r, dataframe

Dispongo de un dataframe con datos de pacientes, y tengo interés en las columnas de fechas de varias pruebas que se les han hecho, así como columnas que indican en qué centro se las han hecho. La mayoría de fechas para un mismo paciente coinciden, pero quiero eliminar las repetidas y conservar las fechas que son distintas por cada paciente. Quiero hacer lo mismo, para las columnas que indican en qué centro se han hecho dichas pruebas (casi siempre se repiten, pero a veces son distintos). **Cada paciente se puede haber hecho hasta 8 pruebas distintas, y por tanto en hasta 8 centros, iguales o no entre ellos**.

Por tanto, mi idea era evaluarlo de fila en fila, y ver si los valores que hay en varias columnas (evaluarlas por tanto juntas, las que son de fechas -hasta 8 posibles por paciente-, y por otro lado de forma conjunta las que indican el centro -hasta 8 por paciente-). **Quiero ver si son iguales y, en caso de serlo, eliminar los repetidos. Si no son iguales, mi idea era guardar los distintos valores en otra columna de resultados ('*dates_evaluation*' en este caso, o bien en otra matriz, donde se guarden las columnas de origen que tienen esos valores distintos, y ver qué valores son.**

Ejemplo del dataframe:

| ID paciente | Fecha prueba 1 | Centro prueba 1 | Fecha prueba 2 | Centro prueba 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I-6245-5539 | 29/06/2021 | ICO | 29/06/2021 | ICO |
| I-4455-3679 | 21/01/2018 | VH | 29/06/2021 | ICO |
| I-3364-4682 | 14/01/2020 | Other |  |  |

No todos los pacientes se han hecho el mismo número de pruebas, por tanto hay bastantes blancos en los datos.

He intentado hacerlo con loops de for + if pero no consigo que funcionen. Mi idea era guardar un vector o matriz con valores lógicos de TRUE/FALSE, para posteriormente filtrar el dataframe y dejar solo las columnas de fechas únicas y centros únicos.

He probado con:

```r
dates_evaluation <- c()
x <- initial_df$ID_paciente   

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {  
  if (initial_df$date1[i] == initial_df$date2[i]) {
    dates_evaluation <- rbind(dates_evaluation, initial_df$dates_evaluation)
  }
}
```

**NOTA:** No he conseguido encontrar los fallos, quizás están en la forma de indexar el dataframe, o la forma en la que planteo el loop for, o el if, y seguramente se pueda hacer de una forma más sencilla (incluso con dplyr).

**Disculpad si no me explico de forma muy clara, soy principiante y me parece bastante complejo explicar lo que quiero hacer sin saber bien bien cómo hacerlo.**

**GRACIAS!!**

Answer (score 2):

`tidyverse/dplyr` se aplica muy bien a tu requerimiento. Imaginando un ejemplo pequeño tal como lo has explicado:

```
initial_df <-  read.table(text= "ID_paciente|date_1|centro_1|date_2|centro_2
I-6245-5539|29/06/2021|ICO|29/06/2021|ICO      
I-4455-3679|21/01/2018|VH|29/06/2021|ICO       
I-3364-4682|14/01/2020|Other|NA|NA", strip.white = TRUE, header=TRUE, sep= '|')

initial_df

  ID_paciente     date_1 centro_1     date_2 centro_2
1 I-6245-5539 29/06/2021      ICO 29/06/2021      ICO
2 I-4455-3679 21/01/2018       VH 29/06/2021      ICO
3 I-3364-4682 14/01/2020    Other       <NA>     <NA>
```

Lo que se puede hacer es:

###### 1. Transformar la estructura "horizontal" en "vertical" mediante `pivot_longer()`

```
initial_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID_paciente,
               names_to = c(".value", "item"), 
               names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID_paciente item  date       centro
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>      <chr> 
1 I-6245-5539 1     29/06/2021 ICO   
2 I-6245-5539 2     29/06/2021 ICO   
3 I-4455-3679 1     21/01/2018 VH    
4 I-4455-3679 2     29/06/2021 ICO   
5 I-3364-4682 1     14/01/2020 Other 
6 I-3364-4682 2     NA         NA
```

###### 2. Agrupar y quedarnos con una sola de las ocurrencias

Viendo los datos anteriores, nos queda claro que el paciente `I-6245-5539` tiene dos observaciones iguales, y es este el caso en el que queremos obviar una de las observaciones:

```
initial_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID_paciente,
               names_to = c(".value", "item"), 
               names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(ID_paciente, date, centro) %>% 
  slice(1)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID_paciente, date, centro [5]
  ID_paciente item  date       centro
  <chr>       <chr> <chr>      <chr> 
1 I-3364-4682 1     14/01/2020 Other 
2 I-3364-4682 2     NA         NA    
3 I-4455-3679 1     21/01/2018 VH    
4 I-4455-3679 2     29/06/2021 ICO   
5 I-6245-5539 1     29/06/2021 ICO
```

###### 3. Reformular los datos de forma horizontal

A los efectos de cualquier análisis el formato último es ideal, por que representa el concepto de 1 fila = 1 observación. Sin embargo podemos volver a un formato horizontal similar al original mediante `pivot_wider()`:

```
initial_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID_paciente,
               names_to = c(".value", "item"), 
               names_sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(ID_paciente, date, centro) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID_paciente,
              names_from = item,
              values_from = c(date, centro)) %>% 
  select(ID_paciente, order(parse_number(names(.))))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   ID_paciente [3]
  ID_paciente date_1     centro_1 date_2     centro_2
  <chr>       <chr>      <chr>    <chr>      <chr>   
1 I-3364-4682 14/01/2020 Other    NA         NA      
2 I-4455-3679 21/01/2018 VH       29/06/2021 ICO     
3 I-6245-5539 29/06/2021 ICO      NA         NA
```